# Use 2 functions in ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass 2 functions in ajax get request. But it doesn't seem to be working. What I am doing wrong here. I have very little ajax/js knowledge. Hence please help me out.

```
ajax: {
    url: "activity.mainActivity",
    type: "GET",
    data: function(data) {
        data.from_date = $("#from_date").val();
        data.to_date = $("#to_date").val();
    },
    function(data) {
        for (var i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (!data.columns[i].search.value)
                delete data.columns[i].search;
            if (data.columns[i].searchable === true)
                delete data.columns[i].searchable;
            if (data.columns[i].orderable === true)
                delete data.columns[i].orderable;
            if (data.columns[i].data === data.columns[i].name)
                delete data.columns[i].name;
        }
        delete data.search.regex;
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Silly me. :-).

```
data: function(data) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data.columns.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (!data.columns[i].search.value)
            delete data.columns[i].search;
        if (data.columns[i].searchable === true)
            delete data.columns[i].searchable;
        if (data.columns[i].orderable === true)
            delete data.columns[i].orderable;
        if (data.columns[i].data === data.columns[i].name)
            delete data.columns[i].name;
    }
    delete data.search.regex;

    data.from_date = $("#from_date").val();
    data.to_date = $("#to_date").val();
}
```